# Angular bs-stepper using ng-for

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, stepper

I am new at angular.
I am trying to do a component which has bs-stepper using ng-for. I am receiving question datas from database. All i want is the user will answer the questions step by step. I need to give "div" different ids. Anyone know how to do that?

I tried to give ng-for index to "div" id

```
<section class="horizontal-wizard">
      <div id="stepper1" class="bs-stepper horizontal-wizard-example">
        <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" class="bs-stepper-header">
          <div class="step" data-target="#a{{i}}">
            <button class="step-trigger">
              <span class="bs-stepper-box"><i data-feather="arrow-left" (click)="horizontalWizardStepperPrevious()" class="align-middle mr-sm-25 mr-0"></i></span>
              <span class="bs-stepper-label">
                <span class="bs-stepper-title">Questions</span>
                <span class="bs-stepper-subtitle">Fill the Blanks</span>
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
          
          
        </div>
        <div class="bs-stepper-content">
          <form (ngSubmit)="(HWForm.form.valid)" #HWForm="ngForm">
            <div>
            <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" id="a{{i}}" class="content">
              <form #accountDetailsForm="ngForm">
                <div class="content-header">
                  <app-questions-item></app-questions-item>
                </div>


                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                  
                  <button
                    (click)="horizontalWizardStepperNext(accountDetailsForm)"
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-next"
                    rippleEffect
                  >
                    <span class="align-middle d-sm-inline-block d-none">Next</span>
                    <i data-feather="arrow-right" class="align-middle ml-sm-25 ml-0"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```